# How to use callback functions in this example?

Tags: javascript

Good evening everyone! I have a small problem with my code that I can't solve correctly. I need to output to the console the simplest recipe for soup through the callback function. Please help with advice. Thank in advanse!

From online tutorials and YouTube, I understand that if we passed one function as a parameter to another function, then this is a callback function.

```js
// Put the water to boil
function setWater(param){
    console.log('We start to cook the soup. We put the water to warm.');
    param();
}

// Chop the onion
function cutOnion(param){
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Chop the onion');
        param();
    }, 5000); 
}

// Chop the carrot
function cutCarrot(param){
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Chop the carrot');
        param();
    }, 6000); 
}

// We are waiting for the water to boil.
function waitForWater(param){
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('We are waiting for the water to boil.');
        param();
    }, 10000); 
}

// Put the onion in the water
function putOnion(param){
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Put the onion in the water');
        param();
    }, 12000); 
}

// Put the carrot in the water
function putCarrot(param){
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Put the carrot in the water');
        param();
    }, 14000); 
}

// Soup Is Ready
function soupIsReady(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Soup is ready');
    }, 20000); 
}

setWater(cutOnion);
cutOnion(cutCarrot);
cutCarrot(waitForWater);
waitForWater(putOnion);
putOnion(putCarrot);
putCarrot(soupIsReady)
```

I need the functions to be executed one after another on a timer.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: You're calling the functions twice. Use a function expression as the callback instead.

Comment: @SLaks Hi! I don't understand how correct I should write the code. In the example above, everything works almost correctly, but repetitions of some functions fall into the console, and I don't understamd why.

Comment: Use `promise` and `async/await`. https://javascript.info/async

Comment: See if you can get it working with `setWater(function() { cutOn... });`, it should get you started.

Comment: @Antonio I should do this with callback functions, I know about async/await

Comment: @Caramiriel thanks. That should help!

Comment: The delays look like they should all start at the same time (as they get bigger), and not the next one after the previous expires... Can you explain?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduceRight` to accumulate the callback chain into one function, and then call it. This way you avoid what is commonly called "call back hell":

```js
[setWater, cutOnion, waitForWater, putOnion, putCarrot, soupIsReady].reduceRight((acc, f) => 
    () => f(() => acc())
)();

function setWater(param){ console.log('We start to cook the soup. We put the water to warm.'); param();}
function cutOnion(param){ setTimeout(() => { console.log('Chop the onion'); param(); }, 500); }
function cutCarrot(param){ setTimeout(() => { console.log('Chop the carrot'); param(); }, 600); }
function waitForWater(param){ setTimeout(() => { console.log('We are waiting for the water to boil.'); param(); }, 1000); }
function putOnion(param){ setTimeout(() => { console.log('Put the onion in the water'); param(); }, 1200); }
function putCarrot(param){ setTimeout(() => { console.log('Put the carrot in the water'); param(); }, 1400); }
function soupIsReady(){ setTimeout(() => { console.log('Soup is ready'); }, 2000); }
```

For the purpose of the demo, I reduced all the delays, so the steps follow each other sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Caramiriel for hint. I have an answer)

```js
function callback(){
    setWater(function() { 
        cutOnion(function(){
            cutCarrot(function(){
                waitForWater(function(){
                    putOnion(function(){
                        putCarrot(function(){
                            soupIsReady();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The use of the word function here is unnecessary. Every thing you're calling inside function() { //here } is already a function... See my answer above.

Comment: @Brant that's not true, see my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see somthing like that...

```js
// Put the water to boil
function setWater(param) {
  console.log('We start to cook the soup. We put the water to warm.');
  fct = param.shift();
  fct(param);
}


// Chop the onion
function cutOnion(param) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Chop the onion');
    fct = param.shift();
    fct(param);
  }, 1000);
}

// Chop the carrot
function cutCarrot(param) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Chop the carrot');
    fct = param.shift();
    fct(param);
  }, 1000);
}

// We are waiting for the water to boil.
function waitForWater(param) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('We are waiting for the water to boil.');
    fct = param.shift();
    fct(param);
  }, 1000);
}

// Put the onion in the water
function putOnion(param) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Put the onion in the water');
    fct = param.shift();
    fct(param);
  }, 1000);
}

// Put the carrot in the water
function putCarrot(param) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Put the carrot in the water');
    fct = param.shift();
    fct(param);
  }, 1000);
}

// Soup Is Ready
function soupIsReady() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Soup is ready');
  }, 1000);
}

setWater([cutOnion, cutCarrot, waitForWater, putOnion, putCarrot, soupIsReady]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stack them all like this as well:

```
setWater(cutOnion(cutCarrot(waitForWater(putOnion(putCarrot(soupIsReady))))));
```

Then remove all your setTimeouts.

Comment: `cutOnion` is a function, `cutOnion(...)` is not. So this will throw, because what you pass as `param` to the function is `undefined`. Only `putCarrot(soupIsReady)` works.